# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly SMDiagnostics, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net

So I am Trying to create a server with a front end in C#. I have a server project (.NETFramework v4.8), a DatabaseLib project(.NETFramework v4.8) and a ClientDesktop project (net7.0-windows)

The error message is:

> Unhandled exception. System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'ClientDesktop.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.
> ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SMDiagnostics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'SMDiagnostics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

I expanded to view the innerException which = null.

I have already tried to clean, rebuild, the projects but whenever I run the ClientDesktop that is the error I get. I have looked through a bunch of online questions which are similar and have also made sure they are all set to AnyCPU and are referenced to eachother.
Any help is appreciated and if any further information is needed please let me know.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migration-wcf-to-corewcf-upgrade-assistant/

Comment: you may need to add the assembly to the ClientDesktop's app manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the error was because I selected the .NET/.NET core Desktop application instead of .NET Framework Desktop application.

This caused compatibility issues between the 3 projects. Thanks for all the help...